# Correct verb patterns for the verb 'recommend'?

Tags: infinitives, verb-patterns

Which of the **last three** verb patterns apply to the verb 'recommend'?

1. > *I recommend that you wait.* (present subjunctive, American usage)
2. > *I recommend that you should wait.* (substitute for present subjunctive, British usage)
3. > *I recommend waiting.* (subject of the gerund not mentioned)
4. > *I recommend you/your waiting* (subject of the gerund mentioned)
5. > *I recommend to wait.* (subject of the infinitive not mentioned)
6. > *I recommend you to wait.* (subject of the infinitive mentioned)

Comment: ***To recommend*** - 
 to advise a particular course of action; to advise somebody to do something - usage -  ***Recommend somebody to do something*** *We'd recommend you to book your flight early.*
***recommend (somebody) doing something*** He recommended reading the book before seeing the movie. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/recommend

Comment: ***to recommend*** - recommend somebody/something (to somebody) to make somebody/something seem attractive or good, 
synonym commend: 
*This system has much to recommend it.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Recommend you to" vs. "recommend that you"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35953/recommend-you-to-vs-recommend-that-you). Also [Recommend someone](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52085/recommend-someone) and [“Recommend you to (do something)” or “Recommend to you to (do something)”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56993/), among others.

Comment: Generally when "saying a word in favour of a person", you would either say *I recommend someone **for** something* or *I recommend someone **to** someone.*

Comment: The object of *recommend* is the thing being recommended.  "I recommend you to wait" would mean that I am, eg, putting you on a list of those people who are supposed to wait for the next airplane.  (Though the construction is not particularly idiomatic.)

Comment: @user58319 In your 4th and 6th examples, the object of recommend is "you" (note that in the 4th, you could also use genitive "your" instead of "you). The non-finite clauses "waiting" and "to wait" are catenative complements of "recommend". In your 1st and 2nd examples, "you" is subject of the subordinate that-clauses which are functioning as complement of "recommend". And in your 3rd example, "waiting" is catenative complement of "recommend". Note that objects are almost always nouns or NPs; clauses are only exceptionally considered as objects.

Comment: @Yay: I ngram viewered 'recommend you for doing' and 'recommend you to do'… The former was not found at all.

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/recommend?q=recommend

Comment: What I meant by "I recommend someone for something" is something like: *I recommended her **for** the job.* https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recommend+him+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecommend%20him%20for%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Yay: I know but as you could see in the question, it is recommend followed by a verb (conjugated or in the infinitive or in the gerund) that I am interested in, not when it is followed by a noun!

Comment: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/recommend-for-somebody-to-do-something.2975732/

Answer (score 0):

Structure **n° 4.** sounds a bit awkward: if it is you I am recommending something to, then the gerund does not need its own subject, you/your is understood. Only if the indirect object of the verb 'recommend' and the subject of the verb 'wait' are different is the subject of the gerund needed. It would sound ok if the subject of the gerund were a third person singular or plural, 'him/his', 'her/her', 'them/their'.

And structure **n° 5.** just does not exist for this verb (no occurrrence on ngram viewer).

Surprisingly, structure **n°6.** works for 'recommend', even when the meaning is not something like 'I will recommend you to wait on Lady So-And-So.', where 'recommending' is 'saying a word in favour of a person' and not 'giving them some advice'. It is, in fact, a simplified form of "I recommend (to) you to wait."

Comment: I think this answer is far more complete than the 3 answers given to "Recommend you to" vs "Recommend that you".